# Scrapy set depth limit per allowed_domains

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am crawling 6 different allowed_domains and would like to limit the depth of 1 domain.  How would I go about limiting the depth of that 1 domain in scrapy?
Or would it be possible to crawl only 1 depth of an offsite domains?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Scrapy doesn't provide anything like this. You can [set the `DEPTH_LIMIT` per-spider](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/935), but not per-domain.

What can we do? [Read the code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/), drink coffee and solve it (order is important).

The idea is to disable Scrapy's built-in [`DepthMiddleware`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/e748ca50ca3e83ac703e02538a27236fedd53a7d/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/depth.py) and [provide our custom one](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html) instead.

First, let's define settings:

- `DOMAIN_DEPTHS` would be a dictionary with depth limits per domain
- `DEPTH_LIMIT` setting we'll leave as a default one in case a domain is not configured

Example settings:

```
DOMAIN_DEPTHS = {'amazon.com': 1, 'homedepot.com': 4}
DEPTH_LIMIT = 3
```

Okay, now the custom middleware (based on `DepthMiddleware`):

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.http import Request
import tldextract


class DomainDepthMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, domain_depths, default_depth):
        self.domain_depths = domain_depths
        self.default_depth = default_depth

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        settings = crawler.settings
        domain_depths = settings.getdict('DOMAIN_DEPTHS', default={})
        default_depth = settings.getint('DEPTH_LIMIT', 1)

        return cls(domain_depths, default_depth)

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        def _filter(request):
            if isinstance(request, Request):
                # get max depth per domain
                domain = tldextract.extract(request.url).registered_domain
                maxdepth = self.domain_depths.get(domain, self.default_depth)

                depth = response.meta.get('depth', 0) + 1
                request.meta['depth'] = depth

                if maxdepth and depth > maxdepth:
                    log.msg(format="Ignoring link (depth > %(maxdepth)d): %(requrl)s ",
                            level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider,
                            maxdepth=maxdepth, requrl=request.url)
                    return False
            return True

        return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
```

Note that it requires [`tldextract`](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract) module to be installed (used for extracting a domain name from url):

```
>>> import tldextract
>>> url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805952/scrapy-set-depth-limit-per-allowed-domains'
>>> tldextract.extract(url).registered_domain
'stackoverflow.com'
```

Now we need to turn off the default middleware and use the one we implemented:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.DomainDepthMiddleware': 900,
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware': None
}
```

Comment: How does tldextract differ from the more popular python package `tld` ?

Comment: @FredericBazin I am not sure really, haven't compared them. I think here it is not very important. You can use any one of them, or even solve it with `urlparse()` having a custom `extract_domain()` function. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation! 
Should `response.meta['depth'] = 0` above `depth = response.meta['depth'] + 1`  Else, `response.meta['depth']` is empty and would give a keyerror

Comment: In last version of Scrapy the default middleware changes name to: `'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware': None`