# Scrapy: parse outgoing domain but do not follow links

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a set of domains I'm crawling with scrapy where I want to check if all outgoing links to 'www.ecommerce.com' are valid/invalid.  I'm using CrawlSpider, but I do not want CrawlSpider to follow the links of the 'www.ecommerce.com', only parse the http status.
How would I get scrapy to parse the outgoing link, but not follow the links on the outgoing link URL?

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from CAP.items import Website
from scrapy.mail import MailSender

from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

class HomeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "capseleniums"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ecommerce.com", "learn.ecommerce.com", "health.ecommerce.com", "wm15.ecommerce.com", "wm13.ecommerce.com", "wm12.ecommerce.com" ]
    handle_httpstatus_list = [500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 408, 404]

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = reversed( [
            'http://wm12.ecommerce.com/health-wellness-center/',
            'http://wm13.ecommerce.com/Cook/',
            'http://wm15.ecommerce.com/electronics-resource-center/',
            'http://health.ecommerce.com/vitamins-wellness-center/',
            'http://learn.ecommerce.com/Tips-Ideas/',
            ] )
        return [ Request(url = start_url) for start_url in start_urls ]

    def trim(link_text):
        return link_text.strip(' \t\n\r')

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=(),
                deny=(),
                process_value=trim,
                restrict_xpaths=("//*[not(@class='GlobalFooter')]","//*[not(@id='footer_links')]")
                ),
                callback="parse_items",
                follow=False,),
    )

    def __init__(self, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--load-images=no'])
        super(HomeSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
       self.driver.stop()

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = self.driver
        hxs.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(1)
        body = hxs.page_source
        sel_response = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=body, encoding = 'utf-8')
        hxs = Selector(sel_response)
        sites = hxs.xpath('//html')
        items = []

        if response.status == 404:
            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['status'] = response.status
                items.append(item)

            return items

        if hxs.xpath('/html/head/title/text()[contains(.,"invalid")]'):
            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['status'] = response.status
                items.append(item)

            return items

        elif hxs.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href[contains(.,"invalid-category-id")]'):
            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['status'] = response.status
                items.append(item)

            return items

        else:
            if hxs.xpath('//*[@class="result-summary-container"]/text()[contains(.,"Showing 0 of")]'):
                for site in sites:
                    item = Website()
                    item['url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                    item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                    item['status'] = response.status
                    items.append(item)

                return items
```

Comment: Setting `DEPTH_LIMIT` per domain might help here - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805952/scrapy-set-depth-limit-per-allowed-domains/27810497#27810497.