# Scrapy: crawl 1 level deep on offsite links

Tags: scrapy

In scrapy how would I go about having scrapy crawl only 1 level deep for all links outside the allowed domains.  Within the crawl, I want to be able to make sure all outbound links within the site are working and not 404'd.  I do not want it to crawl the whole site of the non-allowed domain.  I am currently processing allowed domain 404s.  I know that I can set a DEPTH_LIMIT of 1, but that will affect the allowed domain as well.

my code:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor 

from smcrawl.items import Website
import smcrawl.util 

def iterate(lists):
    for a in lists:
        return a    

class WalmartSpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [200, 302, 404, 500, 502]
    name = "surveymonkeycouk"
    allowed_domains = ["surveymonkey.co.uk", "surveymonkey.com"]    

    start_urls = ['https://www.surveymonkey.co.uk/']    

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=(),
                deny=(),
                process_value=smcrawl.util.trim),
                callback="parse_items",
                follow=True,),
    )
    #process_links=lambda links: [link for link in links if not link.nofollow] = filter nofollow links  

    #parses start urls
    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        list(self.parse_items(response))    

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = response.selector.xpath('//html')
        items = []  

        for site in sites:
            if response.status == 404:            
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
                item['robots'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
                item['original_url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['description'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
                item['redirect'] = response.status    
            elif response.status == 200:            
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
                item['robots'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
                item['original_url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['description'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
                item['redirect'] = response.status        
                titles = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
                try:
                    titles = iterate(titles)
                    titles = titles.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['title'] = titles
                h1 = site.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
                try:
                    h1 = iterate(h1)
                    h1 = h1.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['h1'] = h1    
            elif response.status == 302:
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
                item['robots'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
                item['original_url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['description'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
                item['redirect'] = response.status        
                titles = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
                try:
                    titles = iterate(titles)
                    titles = titles.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['title'] = titles
                h1 = site.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
                try:
                    h1 = iterate(h1)
                    h1 = h1.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['h1'] = h1       
            elif response.status == 404:            
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
                item['robots'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
                item['original_url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['description'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
                item['redirect'] = response.status         
                titles = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
                try:
                    titles = iterate(titles)
                    titles = titles.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['title'] = titles
                h1 = site.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
                try:
                    h1 = iterate(h1)
                    h1 = h1.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['h1'] = h1                                   
            elif response.status == 500:            
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
                item['robots'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
                item['original_url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['description'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
                item['redirect'] = response.status         
                titles = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
                try:
                    titles = iterate(titles)
                    titles = titles.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['title'] = titles
                h1 = site.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
                try:
                    h1 = iterate(h1)
                    h1 = h1.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['h1'] = h1    
            elif response.status == 502:            
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
                item['robots'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
                item['original_url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['description'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
                item['redirect'] = response.status         
                titles = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
                try:
                    titles = iterate(titles)
                    titles = titles.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['title'] = titles
                h1 = site.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
                try:
                    h1 = iterate(h1)
                    h1 = h1.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['h1'] = h1   
            else:           
                item = Website()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
                item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
                item['robots'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="robots"]/@content').extract()
                item['original_url'] = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
                item['description'] = site.xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()
                item['redirect'] = response.status         
                titles = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
                try:
                    titles = iterate(titles)
                    titles = titles.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['title'] = titles
                h1 = site.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
                try:
                    h1 = iterate(h1)
                    h1 = h1.strip()
                except:
                    pass
                item['h1'] = h1                                                  
            items.append(item)  

        return items
```

Comment: can you share your code so far?

Comment: @eLRuLL added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've referred to [Scrapy set depth limit per allowed_domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805952/scrapy-set-depth-limit-per-allowed-domains) as the answer.  It's a little different than the solution I was looking for, but with a whitelist of URLs that I am willing to crawl, then end result is the same.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one thing you could do would be to avoid using `allowed_domains`, so you don't filter any offsite request.

But to make it interesting you could create your own `OffsiteMiddleware`, with something like this:

```
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite import OffsiteMiddleware

class MyOffsiteMiddleware(OffsiteMiddleware):
    offsite_domains = set()
    def should_follow(self, request, spider):
        regex = self.host_regex
        host = urlparse_cached(request).hostname or ''
        if host in offsite_domains:
            return False
        if not bool(regex.search(host)):
            self.offsite_domains.add(host)
        return True
```

I haven't test it, but it should work, remember that you should disable the default middleware and enable yours on settings:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.MyOffsiteMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware': None,
}
```

Comment: could you define `offsite_requests`?

Comment: `self.offsite_domains`.  How would I go about crawling all of the start domain, but only 1 level deep of the external domains?

Comment: I don't get what you mean, have you tried the code above?