# scrapy: Download html for external links

Tags: python, scrapy

Need to crawl all internal as well as external urls on site. Once first external url is crawled I do not want to crawl that external site. URL might be youtube.com which will result in crawling youtube.com completely. Below is code written which does exactly what I want. But I am not able to add that item (external url) in resultant set.

```
import urlparse
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class PropertiesItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    #html = scrapy.Field()  

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ExampleSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["9value.customer360.co"]
    start_urls = ["http://9value.customer360.co/"]

    rules = (
       Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a',)), callback="parse_items", process_links="filter_links", follow= True),
    )

    def filter_links(self, links):
        for link in links:
            if self.allowed_domains[0] not in link.url:
                item = PropertiesItem()
                print '----------------------------- ' + link.url
                item["url"] = link.url
                #item["html"] = response.body
        return links

    def parse_items(self, response):
        item = PropertiesItem()
        item["url"] = response.url
        #item["html"] = response.body
        return(item)
```

Filter_links function filter out external link but does not add value in output json file. Also I want to get HTML for same link.

Comment: I think this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34208378/858913

Comment: If I am not wrong, all links to another domains than `allowed_domainsa` are filtered before your `filter_links` function. That's why it is not adding any external url. That is how `CrawlSpider` is supposed to work.

Comment: I dont think so as my print function works exactly fine. It shows all other domain urls except mentioned in allowed_domains.